# How to remove nodes with the same title from views listing?

Tags: views

Just this, how to remove nodes with the same tilte from views listing?

These nodes are NOT duplicated node, they only have the same title.

Comment: How will Views know which one is the 'correct' one to display, and which one(s) to hide?

Comment: I don't know. But it doesn't matter, any of them will be fine. I just need one node for each title.

Comment: Turn on aggregation and just group by node title then I guess

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this goal via using [Views Distinct](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_distinct) Module.

For more information go through the project documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Download Views Distinct Module and follow the following steps.
Click on the filed title -> under VIEWS DISTINCT SETTINGS select filter repeats from Filter/Aggregate this field dropdown 
[image]